# gedit 3.2.1 File Browser Pane plugin slow and unresponsive

Tags: ubuntu, freeze, gedit, file-browser, gedit-plugin

So i have never really had issues with the `File Browser Plugin` before but since updating to `Ubuntu 11.10`, the version of `gEdit` i have is version 3.2.1. In this plugin I have bookmarks set up for an ssh session.

After connecting to the remote host in the `File Browser Plugin`, if I try to open a directory that contains more than 100 files, gedit becomes unresponsive and what used to be a 10-15 second operation now is a 3-5 minute operation to be able to access those files. It only seems to be a problem when accessing remote directories. Any local directories open instantly.

Has something changed with the new `gEdit`, or the `File Browser Plugin`, or both? Also is there any way to resolve this issue?

There must be some kind of complex indexing which is causing the longer delay.  And I would not be surprised if the new `GTK3 Toolkit` had something to do with this.  But does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: can you provide the version where the expected behavior is present?

Comment: These are the versions of gedit that came preinstalled with Ubuntu 11.04 which I previously had installed.

gedit 2.30.4-2ubuntu1
gedit-common 2.30.4-2ubuntu1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed the latest version of `Ubuntu 12.04`. It comes preinstalled with `gEdit 3.4.1`. Now the `File Browser Plugin` is very responsive and loads 100s of files in just seconds. Good Work Shuttleworth.